# Is it possible to embed xamarin part into an existing native app?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have existing iOS and Android native apps. Is it possible to extend the apps with Xamarin coded part ?

Comment: Just wanted to add link to https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000 which allows you to extend native apps with .NET libraries, it currently only seems to support Objective-C with Java on the way, seems promising though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android are currently setup to take control of your application, so you need to make your main program be written in C# and then call into the existing code.

The way that you would do this is to bind your existing Objective-C or Java code as C# libraries, and then consume those libraries from C#.   The binding technology is precisely what drives both the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android tools, so you would effectively be doing the same.

Once you have bindings, the interoperability works both ways: you can call native code, and native code can call C#.

The bad news is that instead of starting to enjoy writing code with both tools from day zero, the first thing you have to do the bindings, which is in general, not as fun as watching colored squared move on your screen.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, that's what I feared.

Comment: Since this post is few years old already I would like to refresh the topic and ask experienced Xamarin developer if this setup "Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android are currently setup to take control of your application" is still the case? 
Did something change with regard of embedding Xamarin component into existing native iOS and Android applications?

Comment: @lukewar Check out the Embeddinator-4000 project [SteveOLeary mentions, above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291676/is-it-possible-to-embed-xamarin-part-into-an-existing-native-app#comment75243776_17291676). It actually has a page on Microsoft's Xamarin's docs since 2017 called [.NET Embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/). Some [funky limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/limitations), but it sounds like it should be doable.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I find an answer here : http://www.whitneyland.com/2013/05/why-i-dont-recommend-xamarin-for-mobile-development.html

> For example, code written in Xamarin cannot be used in native or HTML5
>   apps.