# How can I create a cross platform library using xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to create a SDK for mobile developers to embed my solution, but instead of writing it in Swift and Java, I would like to use Xamarin to write it once and then export to the selected target.

I'm not sure if it possible, I saw this answer : [Is it possible to embed xamarin part into an existing native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291676/is-it-possible-to-embed-xamarin-part-into-an-existing-native-app)

but it was sometime ago so I wonder if things have changed or if there is a workaround, like writing a small native part just to create the bindings and export this as the sdk then...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK nothing has changed, still not possible.

Comment: ok but then what is the purpose of this http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/registrar/

Comment: That's the bridge to iOS so that iOS native code can create managed objects (i.e. when you override something native) and call into managed code (think events). The same is done with Android through ACW. These bridges work only when Xamarin process is running which is not the case in your scenario.

Comment: Looks like [it might be possible now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291676/is-it-possible-to-embed-xamarin-part-into-an-existing-native-app#comment107949938_17301423).

Comment: Well, in theory. But I'd be skeptical, i.e.there are like 125 open issues and project doesn't look very active. I wonder if there is anything build with it in production.