# Objective C/Android Java calling Xamarin code

Tags: java, android, objective-c, iphone, xamarin

We have Objective C and Andoid Java applications and would like to create a component using C# and Xamarin that would interact.
Is there a way these technologies can communicate with each other (Objective C <-> Xamarin and Android Java <-> Xamarin).
Not sure how you do this but searching here it may be possible to create a static library in Objective C/Java that can be called from Xamarin.

From there I understand that you can start the Objective C/Java app from the Xamarin Main method and afterwards can call other static library methods.
Ideally we would like to call from the Objective C/Java app to Xamarin.

According to Miguel in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291676/is-it-possible-to-embed-xamarin-part-into-an-existing-native-app) it is possible but are there any examples anywhere.

Hope the explanation makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the wording of your question, this is not possible.

Xamarin does offer the ability to create 'bindings' between C# and Objective C/Java static libraries and has a section on the Developer documentation on doing so ([Objective C Bindings](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/) or [Java Wrappers](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/)).

The key part is that this is for static libraries and not for general application functionality i.e. user interactions.

You will need to weigh up the benefit between migrating the disparate projects to a shared Xamarin solution whereby you will enjoy the code sharing (especially with the Xamarin Forms offering) or simply writing the functionality into separate libraries for the different platforms.

Good luck