# Can you have an app that has two embedded apks and runs them?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

So I have two apps that I made. I have two separate apks. I want to create an app, that will have two options as you open the app. Upon clicking the first option the #1 apk runs, upon clicking the second option #2 apk runs. So basically what I want to do is embed two apks in one app. Is this possible to do? Or is there any workaround? I can´t use code, because both are separate development, so the only option is already packaged app.

Comment: "Is this possible to do?" -- fortunately, no. At best, you can have one APK offer to install the second APK, though this may get you banned from major app distribution channels.

Comment: @CommonsWare how is this not a possibility? I don´t want to install two apks. I would like to have only one so the user dosen´t need to install both.

Comment: *"I can´t use code, because both are separate development, so the only option is already packaged app."* - if you / your team / your company are the developers or hired the developer then it surely is an option to change the deployment / packaging. That is the way to go.

Comment: @luk2302 the problem is that one app is written in xamarin and the other one is written in native. What are my options here?

Comment: "how is this not a possibility?" -- you cannot just "run" an Android app. It has to be installed first. That has been how Android has worked since Android 1.0 back in 2008.

Comment: @CommonsWare yea, I know. I want to install one app. But inside this app I want to have two other apks. This should have been worked out somehow. It doesn´t have to be apk if I can export the app in any other kind of way, to be able to then embed it to the "interface app"

Comment: If you only have the APK you are completely out of options i would say. You have to change how both components are built and packaged. You might be able to use the *code* and call native from Xamarin or the other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291676/is-it-possible-to-embed-xamarin-part-into-an-existing-native-app . But maybe the only real option is drop one technology completely. Either native *or* Xamarin.